# Which YARN Scheduler to use for streaming queries?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-structured-streaming

I have about 5 Spark structured streaming applications on Yarn. But I don't know what is the best scheduler for this?

- FIFO Scheduler
- Capacity Scheduler
- Fair Scheduler

I think `Capacity Scheduler` more suitable for this, but I don't know how can I create queues for all streaming applications.

Should I create `queue/subqueue` for each streaming application using `Capacity Scheduler`?

Also, later, I will add `spark batch applications` on the same cluster/resources. Thus, I want to manage all cluster resources with most effective way using schedulers.

Comment: _"But I don't know what is the best scheduler for this?"_ <-- What are the requirements for the streaming queries?

Comment: For example, I have 5 streaming query. Streaming query 1 writes data to kafka, and streaming query 2 and 3 receives the same data from kafka and writes different locations. Last, streaming query 4 and 5 independently running than other streaming queries.

Comment: Why do you think there is *any* difference between the schedulers that would impact a streaming query? I think there's none.

Comment: I dont know. I've read some blogs(for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-streaming-high-availability ), they are generally offers Capacity Scheduler. I really really dont understand that when I should use which scheduler.